# Google sheets COUNTIF containing a cell reference in the criterion

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need a Countif function to run with 2 greater/lesser statements based off of other cells

I tried
=COUNTIF($M$2:$M, ">="&P2,"<="&Q2)and
[image: my other formula attempt]
the first one doesn't work but I don't know why, the second is giving obviously wrong answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS($M$2:$M, ">="&P2,$M$2:$M,"<="&Q2)
```

Comment: that worked amazingly, thank you very much! i assume i just forgot to duplicate the range for the second condition to work?

Comment: Yes, COUNTIF and COUNTIFS work similarly, but that "S" makes the difference, he

Comment: You can add conditions from the same column, but also from other columns the need to be met simultaneously